# can't open src file in html because path doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, total.js

I have a html file in a folder called views, and i run my project using node.
`node index.js` which makes a server using total.js. The server starts running on `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` . This all works fine, except when I try to include a script in  the html:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/js.js">`

I get the following message in the console:

`GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/path/to/js.js"    404 not found`

Comment: Well where is that file located? (Like, what directory?)

Comment: I get the same message, it doesn't matter where I put the file, or the path to the file (even when they are in the same directory)

Comment: It means exactly what it says.  You're not putting the file in the right place or the URL is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the file exists:
`/your-app-directory/public/path/to/js.js`

All JavaScripts are routed to `/your-app-directory/public/js/default.js` by default.